# Disappearing div after varying height in IE10

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a two simple top and bottom rows one on top the other. I have a button when click, it extend the bottom row over the top row making the bottom row the only row.

```
.container-fluid {
    .row.main-body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        >div:first-child {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 100%;
            transition: $transition-length;
            .row.bottom {
                max-height: calc(100% - 356px);
                height: 100%;
                transition: max-height 0.5 ease-in;
                &.hidedashboard {
                    max-height: 100%;
                    transition: max-height $transition-length ease-out;
                    height: -webkit-fill-available;
                    padding-bottom: 7em;
                }
             }
            .row.Top {
                height: 260px;
                transition: height 0.5 ease-in-out;
                &.hidedashboard {
                    height: 0;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }
                &:not(.hidedashboard) {
                    height: 260px;
                }
                .card {
                    max-height: 260px !important;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From the above styling , .row.bottom is the bottom row, and the .row.Top is the row top.

Before hide
[image]

The cycled button toggle the rows. When SHowDashboard is clicked, row.top height change from 0 to 260px . If the HideDashboard is click The height change from 260px to 0.

After hide

[image]

My code works in chrome and IE 11 . So far in IE10, when we hide and show. The top renders blanc, just white screen despite the fact that the HTML is there. While hiding, i can see it shows because of the transition delay. Please how do i address this ? This happens only in IE 10

Comment: what actually you want to do, its everything beating around the bush, can you explain simply

Answer (score 0):

It turns out ie10 has problem with the varying height.So instead of transitioning both two rows, i give the top a fix height as required, and then translate the bottom row over the top row. That way the height doesn't need to change from height: 0 to height: 260px. So basically

```
.container-fluid {
    .row.main-body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        >div:first-child {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 100%;
            transition: $transition-length;
            .row.bottom {
                background-color: $gray-100;
                height: calc(100% - 356px);
                transition: all $transition-length ease-in-out;
                &.hidedashboard {
                    transform: translateY(-260px);
                    height: 100%;
                    height: -webkit-fill-available;
                    padding-bottom: 7em;
                }
             }
            .row.Top {
                height: 260px;
                .card {
                    max-height: 260px !important;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From the above styling , .row.top neither translate nor changes in height. The row.bottom transform vertically instead. When we transform vertically to the top of the top row, it works fine. Thanks